# Time doesn't update during ping process?

Tags: python, networking, ping

How to create a time on python when a process during ping starts like 01:25:25 and finishes like 01:25:39?

I tried to do datetime input but not working just even the seconds still stays the same time as it started when finished.

my code

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

pinghost = input("you want to ping: ")
print("Started " + time)
response = os.system("ping -n 6 {}".format(pinghost))

if response == 0:
    print('ping complete.')
    print("Completed "+time)
else:
    print('ping fail.')
```

Comment: Simply because you never update it. (It does not do that on its own.)

Comment: Try calling `now` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your time variable whenever you're going to use it. `now` would mean the present, when the command is running.

Just use:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

pinghost = input("you want to ping: ")
print("Started " + datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
response = os.system("ping -n 6 {}".format(pinghost))

if response == 0:
    print('ping complete.')
    print("Completed "+datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
else:
    print('ping fail.')
```